# Is this set in complex plane is connected?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness, path-connected

**Question**: let denote $U$ be **unit square** in complex plane, whose corners are $0, 1, i,$ and $1+i$. 
then, the set

$S= \{a+bi: a, b\text{ are rationals inside }U\}$ is connected?

**My attempt**: clearly $S$ is **not** polygonally connected! (Since we can find path between any two points in $S$ which contains the point which do not belongs to $S$) **but this does not show $S$ is connected or not**!

**How to show $S$ is connected or not?** to show not connected: we have to show $S$ can be expressed as disjoint union of two nonempty open subsets of $S$, but I am unable to express $S$ like this! :-( 
So is $S$ is connected? But how? 
Please help me, I am stuck on this

Comment: What about the set of points whose real parts are $>1/ \sqrt(2)$ and its complement?

Comment: Sir, nice hint but, I didn't see **how** those set are **open** in $S$? and why to choose in perticular $1/\sqrt(2)$ ? Sir please help me..

Comment: maybe we can consider it as a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and project it to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The notion of connectedness is defined only for open sets. I mean, if $S$ is a (disjoint) union of open sets, then $S$ is itself open. Is this obvious for your $S$? Otherwise, we will have to work with $S$ as a connected topological space in its own right, rather than as a subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I'm assuming that your space has the subspace topology.  That is, it's open if it is the intersection of $S$ with an open set of the complex plane with the usual topology.  As to why $1/\sqrt(2)$ any irrational number between $0$ and $1$ will serve.  Do you see why $1/2$ for instance, wouldn't work?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Sir, but not oblivious for me. How to express $S$ as disjoint union of open sets? In particular, as "saulspatz" sir, gives two sets, how to show they are open in $S$ and their union is $S$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi See, the issue is this : what is the definition of disconnectedness? Some subset $S$ is said to be disconnected if $S$ can be written as the disjoint union of two non-empty open subsets, right? But then, the union of two open subsets is open, so $S$ must be open. But it is *not*. So what do we do? We have to change our definition of connectedness for this. We define disconnectedness like *this* now : $S$ is disconnected if there are disjoint open sets $U_1,U_2$ such that $S = (S \cap U_1) \cup (S \cap U_2)$, where both intersections are non-empty. Continued...

Comment: Now, what has been done, is that saulspatz has given you the sets $S \cap U_1$ and $S \cap U_2$. What you have to say, is that the set $\{a + bi : a > \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\}$ is the intersection of $S$ with some open set $U_1$ in the complex plane. If you can do this, that is come up with an open $U_1$ so that $S \cap U_1 = \{a+bi : a > \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\}$, then this qualifies to be $(S \cap U_1)$ in the definition of disconnectedness. Similarly for $U_2$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Sir, "which open set $U_1$ and _$U_2$"? Unable to find them....:-(

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Consider the open set $U_1 = \{a + bi : a < \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\}$.

Comment: Can't understand your set. Does you mean $S=\{a+bi \text{ | }a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and }a,b \text{ inside } U\}$ or $S=\{a+bi \text{ | }a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and }a+bi\text{ inside } U\}$?

Comment: @positrón0802 sir, the first one that you mentioned

Comment: But then why take that $U$ and not just the interval $[0,1]$? The rationals in $U$ are just the rationals in $[0,1].$

Comment: Sir, I don't know, I typed the question, as it is, as given in textbook

Answer (score 0):

I don't know answering our own question is fine or not. But, I think it is best way to know ,"what we get from others helpful comments". @Saulspatz sir, and @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Sir, please check is this is correct.

define $U_1=\{a+bi: a<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$ and $U_2=\{a+bi: a>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$

both are open sets in $\mathbb{C}$ and hence, by definition of subspace topology, $S∩U_1$ and $S∩U_2$ are open sets in $S$  and clearly
$S= S∩U_1∪S∩U_2$ and so $S$ is written as disjoint union of nonempty open sets and hence $S$ is disconnected.

Comment: I don't know how actually $S∩U_1$ and $S∩U_2$ looks in complex plane? any help in this?